# ASP.NET feature similar to WPF/XAML ValueConverter?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, eval

I have a DataList that is bound against some very lightweight objects.

I'm writing the ItemTemplate for my objects and the first entry is simple enough:

```
<h2>'<%# Eval("Name") %>'</h2>
```

For the next entry however, I want to use several bits of information in the object and combine that into a string. So I would want to do something like:

```
<p>'<%# CallACustomTypeConverterDefinedInDllXYZ(onTheBoundObject) %>'</p>
```

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for? What's the common practice?